# How do I classify data in C++ using a trained classifier from Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, machine-learning, export, classification

I guess there are two possible ways:

1. Export the trained classifier to C++ in a way, such that a machine
   learning package in C++ is able to make predictions based on the
   trained classifier
2. Make predictions based on the parameters in the trained
   classifier using my own algorithm.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with any of the algorithms used by the classification learner in Matlab to write my own algorithm without a little help.

So if there is no possibility for option 1. it would be great if you could help me with 2. Maybe someone has done this before? Any of the learning algorithms from the Matlab toolbox would be fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], and read about [ask] a good question.

Comment: I know i'm off on a tangent but If you have time i recommend learning tensorflow the language is in python but it has a c++ api. https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials is well documented. I have learned quite a lot from it.

Comment: Your question is too broad, without knowing what kind of classifier you are using its difficult to evaluate your options.

Comment: Okay, then maybe let's try the easiest (?) one, the linear discriminant classifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classifier is linear as in logistic regression / SVM, you can just export the trained parameters which is a matrix of size n_features x n_labels and import it in C++. Given a new input you can extract the features and multiply the vector and this matrix.

If not, you can [call](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-matlab-software-from-a-c-application.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) MATLAB from C++.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess the parameters are stored in the first column ("Estimate") of _trainedClassifier.GeneralizedLinearModel.Coefficients_ ? I would like to have a classification of the form prediction = sign(w^T * x)

Comment: Yeah, that coefficients are the parameters a matrix of size n_feature x n_labels which you can save and use anywhere.

Comment: what about other kind of classifier? such as Knn classifier. How can we then extract the parameters to C++?

Comment: those are more complicated because the data structure is a tree (ball tree, k-d tree) and you need to find a way to store and do search over those trees, alternatively you can retrain your models in a C++ library like mlpack which support knn.